# Can you please tell me whats wrong in this SEARCH function in quadrartic probing implementation of hash table using C?

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, hashtable

Can you suggest me the best version for the SEARCH function code.
when i compile , it is showing as "Unreachable code ". Please check.
I just decided not to use pointers in this implementation.

```
define TS 10

int ht[TS] = {}, s = 0;

int search(int key) {

  int ind, i = 0, hk;
  hk = key % TS;
  while (i != hk) {
    ind = (hk + i) % TS;
    if (ht[ind] == key) {
      printf("value is found at ind %d\n ", ind);
      return ind;
      break;
    }
    s = s++;
    i = (s * s) % TS;
  }
  if (i == hk) {
    printf("value not found\n");
    return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `break;` statement never reaches as the function would `return ind;` before that

Comment: Your code is not a [MRE] and it is not C++. C++ and C are very different languages. With C++, you would use [C++ standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: Also, read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The C language is defined in [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). The C++ language is defined in [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). You can easily see that they are very different. Read also wikipages on [C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) and on [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), you will understand that they are different

Comment: Generally please identify the line to which any error message or warning refers. That mininises the amount of guessing potential answerers have to do and thereby increases your chances that they will actually answer. Do so by adding a comment `/* line with error/warning */`, because line numbers are unreliable when posted here.

Comment: The expression `s = s++` causes undefined behaviour, though it is unrelated to "Unreachable code" issue.